# Why is client receving only child output when server is executing a program with a fork?

Tags: c, server, udp, client, fork

I have a server in C using DGRAM socket connection and the corresponding client.

When the client connects the server executes the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    printf("Hello from parent\n");
    pid_t pr;

    if(pr = fork()>0)
    {
        wait(&status);
        return 0;
    }
    execv( "Path/to/child/child", 0);
    return 0;

}
```

The behaviour I do not understand is the following: the response sent to the client is the prints of the child process, the parent output seems completely bypassed. To be clearer I was expecting that the client would receive from the server the message:

```
Hello from parent
Hello from child
```

while the client is receiving only

```
Hello from child
```

Note that launching from the terminal will print both the parent and child outputs.

However if I completely remove the `fork()` block, the client will receive the parent output (the child doesn't even exist in this case):

```
Hello from parent
```

Why in the first case is the client receiving only the child output and not the parent?

The child output can be anything for example I used this (C):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello from child\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Server and client codes can be found [here](https://github.com/FrancescoBoi/client-Server-C) (code is too long to be posted here): the files are `connectionlessClient.c` and `connectionlessServer.c` and the can be compiled with make (if on you can run directly the executables). Just change the program to be executed in the server: the line to be chaged is:

```
if ((fp = popen("...", "r")) == NULL)
```

Comment: What does the client receive if you make the child `sleep()` for a while before letting it end?

Comment: The `sleep` has effect but does not change the received string from the client. I also tried to put a `sleep()` in the parent: same stuff: it waits longer but the output set to the client does not change.

Comment: Mind showing the code which does the actual reading until pclose is called?

Comment: You mean the client server code?